# Can't install windows feature windows server backup on server 2012R2 0x800f0922 DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

When I trying to install from wizard, getting error 0x800f0922.

From PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\Администратор.WIN-TIR7J3CUJLQ> Add-WindowsFeature Windows-Server-Backup -Source c:\test\sources\sxs
Add-WindowsFeature : Сбой запроса на добавление или удаление компонентов на указанном сервере.
Сбой установки одной или нескольких ролей, служб ролей или компонентов. Ошибка: 0x800f0922
строка:1 знак:1
+ Add-WindowsFeature Windows-Server-Backup -Source c:\test\sources\sxs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : **DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand**

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
False   No             Failed         {}
```

Updates on the server is working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you install WSB without specifying the sources ? i.e: `Add-WindowsFeature Windows-Server-Backup`

Comment: the same error(